# How to show the running time of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

The outer loop runs $n$ times. The inner loop runs $\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \rfloor$ times. So it would be $O(n \cdot \lfloor \frac{n}{i} \rfloor)$. I do not know how to transform that into a proper expression involving Big Oh and n. Maybe it could be first expressed as a sum:

$\qquad\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n \frac{n}{j}$.

```
for i = 1 to n:
    j = i
    while j ≤ n:
        A[j] = A[j] + 1
        j = j + i
```

Could you please indicate, apart from the actual running time of the algorithm, how to show the said running time?

Comment: Our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) gives you the general method. You can check out other [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops] questions for examples.

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction. I hope I did transcribe your sum-thing correctly?

Comment: Why do you think the inner loop will execute $n/i$ times?